# How can I filter a collection with Backbone Paginator, including items not on current page?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-paginator

I'm using Backbone Paginator, and when I filter the collection, it only filters the current page.  How can I filter for the entire collection?

Currently, I'm handling a filter button in Marionette.  When the user enters the value to filter for, I set the value as a member in my Application object.  Then I call fetch on the collection.  These items are in a table, rendered in a Composite View.  I override the filter method and return 0 if the data field in the model doesn't match the criteria in the filter value:

```
filter: function(child, index, collection) {
  var name = child.get('full_name').toLowerCase();
  if (App.nameFilter.length) {
    if (name.indexOf(App.nameFilter.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

If the child model isn't on the current page, it doesn't get picked up.  Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you find a solution for your problem, but the filtering in marionette doesn't affect the collection managed by Paginator this is the reason that cause the bug on the pagination.

I'm working on a similar stuff too and I think the only way is to manage the filtering directly in the collection